# Display subreports in Pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am having an issue getting my sub-report to show up in Pentaho Report Designer.

I have actually followed all steps described in a tutorial, but I still can't see my chart in the preview.

I don't know if I need to activate an option or not.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can see the effort that you have put forth into coming up with a solution. Without seeing what you have already done, we cannot help you.

Comment: The problem is not with the code or the queries that I've written. Because they are displayed in a normal report. The problem is when I want to display the three charts in the same report. I know that i should use the subreport. It's not working in my machine. Cant detect why !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have you imported your fields (and perhaps parameters) from the main report into the subs. Often this would be the case a sub-report fails to show.